# Proving a Square Root of a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> For a real symmetric $2\times2$ matrix $A$, we define a $2\times2$ matrix $\sqrt{A}$ that satisfies $\sqrt{A}r_1=\sqrt{\lambda_1}r_1,\ \sqrt{A}r_2=\sqrt{\lambda_2}r_2$ where $r_1, r_2$ are the eigenvectors of $A$, and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the corresponding eigenvalues. Show that $(\sqrt{A})^2$ is indeed equal to $A$.

I know this is true but it obvious to me, but I don't know how to start proving it.

Comment: If two linear maps on a vector space agree on the elements of a basis, then ....

Comment: Hi Miriam, welcome to MSE. Reposting questions is generally considered a poor conduct on this site. Please refrain from doing it again. I have closed your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431665/linear-algebra-square-root-question).

Answer (score 2):

$$
(\sqrt{A})^2r_j=\lambda r_j,\quad j=1,2
$$
Pick $\{r_1,r_2\}$ to be an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and see w.r.t this basis

$$
A=(\sqrt{A})^2=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What does "w.r.t." mean?

Comment: with respect to : )

Comment: Why can you just take the square-root of A and leave the vector untouched?

Comment: Is it legal to do and will preserve the matrix A?

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with $\sqrt A$ just name it $B$, $B^2r_j=\lambda_j r_j$, what's illegal about thinking 'bout square of a square matrix?

Comment: could you show that line again?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- If you show that $A v_i= Bv_i$ for all elements of a basis$ \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you habe proven that $A=B$ by linearity of those functions.
- $\{r_1,r_2\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.